# Getting Error: `Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TimelockController: underlying transaction reverted'"`

Tags: blockchain, hardhat, openzeppelin, dao

I am using openzepellin Govenance Wizard contract & openzepellin TimelockController .
I am getting this error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'TimelockController: underlying transaction reverted'
```

I suspect the error has something to do with `AccessControl.sol` or `Unsuccessful Proposal` but I don't seem to be able to locate the error.

#### Reproduce the Error

You can clone [this](https://github.com/sadityakumar9211/vyrochain) repository and `cd` into the `vyrochain-hardhat` directory.
Run following commands after installing all the dependencies using `yarn`:

```bash
yarn hardhat node
```

In the new terminal, run the following commands side-by-side:

```bash
yarn hardhat run scripts/changeChairperson/propose.js --network localhost
```

```bash
yarn hardhat run scripts/changeChairperson/vote.js --network localhost
```

```bash
yarn hardhat run scripts/changeChairperson/queue-and-execute.js --network localhost
```

After the execution of the last command, I am getting the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the script on the local development network if error came from the execute fx specifically, it might be that the timelock is not the owner of the contract you want to be governed, try transferring ownership of the governed contract to timelock contract